# How to generate a select dropdown list of names and group them with optgroup in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, select, optgroup

The primary data are about 5000 key:value pairs in an object.
The structure looks like this:

```
var data = {
    '1:2':'Bolivia',
    '1:1':'Austria',
     ...
     ...
     ...
    '100:100':'Zair',
    '80:40':'Greece',
    '20:60':'France'
};
```

The 1st step should be to sort the object by it's values.
I have accomplished this with the following code:

```
data = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).sort((a,b)=>a[1]>b[1]?1:((b[1]>a[1])?-1:0)));
```

The 2nd step is to create the labels for the optgroups with the following code:

```
var fl = [...new Set(Object.values(data).map(name=>name.charAt(0)))];
```

The 3rd step is to begin the generation of the list by creating the "no selection" option for the dropdown menu with the following code:

```
var options = '<option value="0:0">----</option>';
```

The 4th step is to generate the optgroups with the following code:

```
$.each(fl,function(k,L)
{
    options += '<optgroup label="'+L+'"></optgroup>';
});
```

The HTML code with the select element:

```
<select id="names"></select>
```

Then I attached the optgroups in the select element with:

```
$('#names').html(options);
```

Final step is to generate the list inside each optgroup:

```
$.each(islandnames,function(c,n)
{
    $('#names optgroup[label="'+n.charAt(0)+'"]').append('<option value="'+c+'">'+n);
});
```

All the used code in one block:

```
<html><body>
<select id="names"></select>
<script>
var data = {
    '1:2':'Bolivia',
    '1:1':'Austria',
     ...
     ...
     ...
    '100:100':'Zair',
    '80:40':'Greece',
    '20:60':'France'
};
data = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data).sort((a,b)=>a[1]>b[1]?1:((b[1]>a[1])?-1:0)));
var fl = [...new Set(Object.values(data).map(name=>name.charAt(0)))];
var options = '<option value="0:0">----</option>';
$.each(fl,function(k,L)
{
    options += '<optgroup label="'+L+'"></optgroup>';
});
$('#names').html(options);
$.each(data,function(c,n)
{
    $('#names optgroup[label="'+n.charAt(0)+'"]').append('<option value="'+c+'">'+n);
});
</script>
</body></html>
```

The code looks that it works but there are some performance issues, I think.
It takes about two seconds to generate the dropdown list and I would like to ask if there is a shorter of even faster way to have the same result?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Full code here: [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/panos78/5j68Ltc9/)

Comment: 5000 <option> in a select will make for a horrible user experience above and beyond the rendering performance. Suggest you look into using an autocomplete/typeahead component instead. Or a cascading set of `<select>`

Comment: That would be an option, but the users of don't know the actual names of the object. In my example, I changed to sth more readable. A cascading set can't be done, as there is no more space in the page, with the current design. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like pop up modal UI time

Comment: Can you be more specific? I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: I mean if design doesn't offer enough room a modal/dialog might help

Comment: Well, I was asked to make just one select with groups. I just follow orders.

Comment: If you need to load all the items right away, you will have just to take the performance hit. If you can cache the items and load just a small part of the items up front and then load more later, this could improve the initial performance.

Comment: The strange is that when I tried to handle all this with no optgroups it has no performance issues and everything runs with no problems. When I implemented the optgroups the problem started. Tha's why, I look for a smarter, faster way to generate the list.